# bulk upload on elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, connection, bulk

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as ES
import json

json_data[]
with open('00.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        json_data.append(json.loads(line))

t = '\n'.join(str(item) for item in json_data)

es = ES('127.0.0.1:9200/')
ES_INDEX = 'myindex'
ES_TYPE = 'doc'

es.bulk(ES_INDEX, ES_TYPE, t)
```

elasticsearch.exception.TransportError: Transport error (406, u'Cone\tent Header [ ] is not supported')

Comment: Make sure to also add a new line character after the last line.

Comment: @Val but how will that solve my connection issue?

Comment: That's a different issue that has probably nothing to do with the ES bulk call. Can you ping localhost:9200 from your host?

Comment: @Val I checked that. Using Request.get it is working. also on URL it is working but using Curl it says localhost couldnt resolve. I also tried it on postman and it gave a green flag

Comment: @Val it is something to do with es.bulk.

Comment: have you tried to add the newline character at the end like I suggested? Also when using `es.bulk()` you can simply pass `json_data` and the method will do the rest for you. See what it does [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/49af6df63115d805e9690e05df20634550eb1589/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#L194-L203)

Comment: @Val: when i uploaded json_data it gave me an error saying string expected and dict found hence I did that. Also i'll try with adding \n at the end

Comment: Which version of ES and the Python library are you using? Also how big is your `00.json` file? And do you see any errors in the ES logs?

Comment: @Val the ELK installed on my system is 5.4.x and python is 2.7. 00.json is 196KB. It has around 121 json lines.

Comment: @Val: I will later have around 100 such 00.json files to bulk upload

Comment: And do you see any errors in the ES logs?

Comment: @Val my es log has an error dated for 17/07/2017 which states unexpected character 'u' and was expecting a double-quote to start field name along with some constructerror(jsonParser..)

Comment: Oh, indeed, you also need to dump your JSON data, so use `json.dumps(item)` instead of `str(item)`. And actually, you don't even need to call `json.loads` in the first place, unless you want to validate that your JSON is well-formed.

Comment: @Val I did that, and i changed localhost:9200 to 127.0.0.1:9200, now I am getting TransportError 406, u'Content-Type header [] is not supported'

Comment: We got one step further, now to figure out why the Python client doens't send the mandatory `Content-type` HTTP header.

Comment: @Val is it something where i will have to define my contents as json application? isnt that solved by ES?
url = "http://localhost:8080"
data = {'sender': 'Alice', 'receiver': 'Bob', 'message': 'We did it!'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

Comment: pretty sure your Python ES client is not 5.4 compliant. Which version are you using? (note: not asking for the Python version) You should also use release 5.4.0 of the `elasticsearch-py` client.

Comment: @Val i checked the ES.info() and it gives a lucene_version 6.5.1 and a version number 5.4.3.  I am currently using Windows 7.

Comment: @Val any help??

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothing wrong with your code.

The problem is it cannot connect to ES. I think the problem is resolving localhost, try making it 127.0.0.1:9200. If it is a Linux machine then try changing your /etc/hosts file to resolve localhost.

Comment: I did that, i seem to be getting TransportError 400: too long frame exception

Comment: Can you tail the ES logs and update with the error stack? Also, is your index and/or type too long by any chance?

Comment: type is doc and my index is one word.

Comment: the last log reflecting on ES log is dated for 17/07/2017